# implement stop function for async receiver in zeromq (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, zeromq

I would like to implement a 'stop' function to shutdown a zeromq Subscriber after it gets into a loop of async receive.

```
import { Subscriber } from 'zeromq';

class DataConsumer {
    subscriber: Subscriber;

    constructor() {
        this.subscriber = new Subscriber();
        this.subscriber.connect('tcp://192.168.0.2:9000');
    }

    async listen(): Promise<void> {
        while (true) {
            const [topic, body] = await this.subscriber.receive();
            this.process(topic, body);
        }
    }

    process(topic: Buffer, body: Buffer) {
        //...
    }

    stop() {
       //... how to break the listen loop?
    }
}

test('test zeromq subscriber receives cancel', async () => {
    const dc = new DataConsumer();
    dc.listen();

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

    dc.stop();   // <===== how to implement stop
});
```

[`Subscriber.receive()`](https://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/classes/subscriber.html#receive) is an async function which returns a promise of multi part message.
The timeout of `receive` is forever by default, but I can also set a timeout value. However, if I use the timeout function, the listen function will turn into polling. Is it possible to keep the function a true asynchronous function but allows stopping it externally?

Comment: I can set timeout for the receive function, but it will turn the function into polling rather than true async.

Comment: Close the `subscriber`?